# React (16.4.1) setState() updates state one onChange event behind the current onChange event with react-select component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have 2 react-select components and the behavior I wish to set is that when the user makes their selection from both select components (order does not matter) then an ajax will be triggered to pull the data from the server.  The selection from both of these components is required to fully populate the GET parameters for the ajax call.

I have these 2 handlers for the onChange event on the react-select elements:

```
filterSiteSelect(selection) {
    const siteId = selection.id;
    const siteName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        siteId, siteName
    }, this.getTableData());
}

filterLineTypeSelect(selection) {
    const lineTypeId = selection.id;
    const lineTypeName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        lineTypeId, lineTypeName
    }, this.getTableData());
}
```

And my getTableData() method looks like:

```
getTableData() {
    const {
        productId, siteId, lineTypeId, stages, tableUrl
    } = this.state;

// tableUrl = `p=field&t=view&gapi=1&product_id=${productId}&site_id=${siteId}&line_type_id=${lineTypeId}&stage_ids=${stages}`

    if (productId && siteId && lineTypeId && !_.isEmpty(stages)) {
        Axios.get(tableUrl)
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    rawData: { ...result.data.data }
                });
            });
    }
}
```

The behavior I am experiencing is that when the user select's an option from the second select box the ajax call does not fire.  The user needs to go back and select something else to get the ajax call to fire and then it uses the first selection they chose.

I also tried to use `ComponentDidUpdate()` for the ajax call with this code (I removed the `getTable()` data from each of the `setState()` calls when I changed to `componentDidUpdate(prevState)`):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    const {
        siteId, lineTypeId, stages
    } = this.state;

    if (lineTypeId !== prevState.lineTypeId && siteId !== prevState.siteId && !_.isEqual(stages, prevState.stages)) {
        this.getTableData();
    }
}
```

But what happens when using the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method it fires the ajax over and over never stoping and I believe that is because the `setState()` is never updating the state for the last select component the user interacted with.

So I think I'm doing something wrong in my use/understanding of the `setState()` method (or the issue lies in the react-select component...).

Any insight, assistance, or discussion of what I'm trying to accomplish would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a second argument to `setState()`, e.g. `setState({foo: bar}, <something>)`, the `<something>` is supposed to be a *callback function* that gets called when `setState()` has finished updating. In your code, instead of passing your function `this.getTableData` as an argument, you are passing the *expression returned from calling* `this.getTableData()`, in this case `undefined`.

In your code here:

```
filterSiteSelect(selection) {
    const siteId = selection.id;
    const siteName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        siteId, siteName
    }, this.getTableData());
}

filterLineTypeSelect(selection) {
    const lineTypeId = selection.id;
    const lineTypeName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        lineTypeId, lineTypeName
    }, this.getTableData());
}
```

When you synchronously call `setState()` and add a state update to the queue, you are also synchronously calling `this.getTableData()` which runs immediately, checks some booleans in your state variables, maybe tries to do an ajax call, etc.

Try simply removing the `()` so that you're passing the function directly into `setState` as an argument instead of accidentally calling the function. :)

```
filterSiteSelect(selection) {
    const siteId = selection.id;
    const siteName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        siteId, siteName
    }, this.getTableData);
}

filterLineTypeSelect(selection) {
    const lineTypeId = selection.id;
    const lineTypeName = selection.name;

    this.setState({
        lineTypeId, lineTypeName
    }, this.getTableData);
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you! And thank you for describing the different of what I was doing.  Passing the reference (pulling out the ()'s) did the trick! I'm very glad to know it was just a dunce moment for me and not a total misunderstanding of how setState works!

Answer (score 0):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)'s second parameter is a callback. That means you should be passing a reference to the function to call, instead of calling the function itself.

```
this.setState({
    siteId, siteName
}, this.getTableData());
```

Should be

```
this.setState({
    siteId, siteName
}, this.getTableData);
```